# Understanding KMP solution - Brute Force

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Hi I am trying to understand KMP solution by brute force. I picked up the solution at leetcode.

```
public static int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
    if (needle == null || needle.length() < 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length() - needle.length() + 1; i++) {
        if (isValid(haystack, needle, i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static boolean isValid(String haystack, String needle, int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < needle.length(); i++) {
        if (haystack.charAt(index + i) != needle.charAt(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here we are doing `haystack.length() - needle.length() + 1`. I am not able to understand why in the for loop we subtracting haystack and needle length and then adding 1 to it. Could some one please help me understand why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first character of `needle` in `haystack` cannot come after position `haystack.length - needle.length - 1` because there would not be enough characters to match. Function `isValid` would even throw an array index out of bounds, because `haystack.charAt(index + i)` would not be defined for all `0 <= i < needle.length`.